# Nokia OVI services access by .NET aplication

Tags: c#, nokia

Is there any chance to add and edit tasks or calendar items on [Nokia OVI Site](http://www.ovi.com/services/) account using C#

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Do you want to develop a C# desktop client for accessing one's OVI account? Do you want to develop a tasks/calendar mobile application in C# and run it on nokia handsets?

Comment: I am trying to make Win APP that will sync my Calendar items and Tasks whit Ovi Suite WEB application . Question is same as this one but regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445651/how-to-create-task-using-google-calendar-api-c/2445657#2445657 to Nokia

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [OVI SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Ovi/Develop_with_Ovi.xhtml) is what you are looking for.
Unfortunately, it is in closed beta right now and seems to focus more on location-based applications than tasks/calendar.

Comment: I fund OVI SDK web page and I did register for making APP but no response from OVI and no access to download SDK or any tool for begin coding